# Visual studio selected code formatting

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I select a part of code and press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D, code in complete file is being formatted.

Is it possible to somehow tell Visual Studio to format *only a piece of code*, like e.g. selected part of code?

Btw, I'm using VS2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>: Format Selection.

You could have discovered that by selecting some text and typing `Format` into the Quick Launch bar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>)

Comment: Whoops! Hehe, great. A bit confusing though. It could have been the same shortcut from usability point of view.

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: On the contrary.  I want to be able to format the document without clearing the selection.